# Можно ли применять условия в css без помощи js?

Tags: css

Дан макет с картинками: если картинок больше двух, z-index самый большой у четных картинок, если картинок меньше двух - z-index больший у нечетных. Можно ли это реализовать без помощи js?

Answer (score 1):

как бы да, но способ так себе, да и не совсем "да" ибо смещение условия может всё поломать.

```css
img{
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid black;
position: relative;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}

img:only-child:nth-child(odd){
z-index:5;
left: 20px;
background: pink;
}

img:not(:only-child):nth-child(even)
{
z-index:4;
background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div id='x'>
<img alt='1'/>
<img alt='2'/>
<img alt='3'/>
<img alt='4'/>
<img alt='5'/>
<img alt='6'/>
</div>
```